# When should I use IEnumerator for looping in c#?

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, loops

I was wondering if there are any times where it's advantageous to use an IEnumerator over a foreach loop for iterating through a collection? For example, is there any time where it would be better to use either of the following code samples over the other?

```
IEnumerator<MyClass> classesEnum = myClasses.GetEnumerator();
while(classesEnum.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(classesEnum.Current);
```

instead of

```
foreach (var class in myClasses)
    Console.WriteLine(class);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, note that one big difference in your example (between `foreach` and `GetEnumerator`) is that `foreach` guarantees to call `Dispose()` on the iterator if the iterator is `IDisposable`. This is important for many iterators (which might be consuming an external data feed, for example).

Actually, there are cases where `foreach` isn't as helpful as we'd like.

First, there is the "first item" case discussed [here (foreach  / detecting first iteration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420774/foreach-with-generic-list-detecting-first-iteration-when-using-value-type#420786).

But more; if you try writing the missing `Zip` method for stitching two enumerable sequences together (or the `SequenceEqual` method), you find that you can' use `foreach` on both sequences, since that would perform a cross-join. You need to use the iterator directly for one of them:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Zip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> left,
    IEnumerable<T> right)
{
    using (var iter = right.GetEnumerator())
    {
        // consume everything in the first sequence
        foreach (var item in left)
        {
            yield return item;

            // and add an item from the second sequnce each time (if we can)
            if (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return iter.Current;
            }
        }
        // any remaining items in the second sequence
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return iter.Current;
        }                
    }            
}

static bool SequenceEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> left,
    IEnumerable<T> right)
{
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    using (var iter = right.GetEnumerator())
    {
        foreach (var item in left)
        {
            if (!iter.MoveNext()) return false; // first is longer
            if (!comparer.Equals(item, iter.Current))
                return false; // item different
        }
        if (iter.MoveNext()) return false; // second is longer
    }
    return true; // same length, all equal            
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like while(iter.MoveNext()) in case right has two or more elements than left?

Comment: Hi Marc, very good answer! Will you elaborate on what you mean by "performing a cross-join"?

Comment: @Nameless maybe I'm abusing SQL terminology, but by a cross-join I simply mean the cartesian product between the two sets

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 19):

According to the [C# language spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx):

> A foreach statement of the form

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

> is then expanded to:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
            V v;
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                    v = (V)(T)e.Current;
                    embedded-statement
            }
    }
    finally {
            ... // Dispose e
    }
}
```

The essense of your two examples are the same, but there are some important differences, most notably the `try`/`finally`.

Comment: Interesting because this also shows what kind of implicit conversions (optionally User-defined) can be triggered

Answer (score 12):

In C#, `foreach` is doing exactly the same thing as the `IEnumerator` code that you posted above. The `foreach` construct is provided to make it easier for the programmer. I believe that the IL generated in both cases is the same/similar.

Comment: There are cases where you need to do it manually - see my answer below.

Comment: Actually, no the IL is **not** identical in his sample, because he hasn't checked the iterator for IDisposable. This is important for many iterators.

Answer (score 4):

I used it sometimes when the first iteration do something different from others.

For example, if you want to print members to console and separate results by line, you can write.

```
using (IEnumerator<MyClass> classesEnum = myClasses.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (classEnum.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(classesEnum.Current);
    while (classesEnum.MoveNext()) {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(classesEnum.Current);
    }
}
```

Then the result is

```
myClass 1
-----------------
myClass 2
-----------------
myClass 3
```

And another situation is when I iterate 2 enumerators together.

```
using (IEnumerator<MyClass> classesEnum = myClasses.GetEnumerator()) {
    using (IEnumerator<MyClass> classesEnum2 = myClasses2.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (classesEnum.MoveNext() && classEnum2.MoveNext())
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", classesEnum.Current, classesEnum2.Current);
    }
}
```

result

```
myClass 1, myClass A
myClass 2, myClass B
myClass 3, myClass C
```

Using enumerator allows you to do more flexible on your iteration. But in most case, you can use foreach

Comment: First iteration: You can use foreach( var item in myList.Select(val, index)) to get the index of the current element. With an extension method, you can even write foreach(var item in myList.SelectWithIndex())