# Type to track the position of a list using IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I’m trying to develop a type to track the current iteration position with a list.

I ideally want to used it with a foreach loop using the IEnumerable interface but the interface has no start/stop events or method to hooking to reset the count.

Currently I have created a GetNext( ) method which return the next value in the list and increments a count by 1.

Does anyone know I can achieve the same functionality using IEnumerable so I can use the type with a foreach loop?

So for example; imagine a list contains 10 items. One method could iterate an instance of the type to position 4 then method two would iterate the same instance starting at position 5 to 6 then method 3 would iterate the remainng from position 7  to 10 – so the type instance tracks the current position.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated (code shown below) . Thanks

```
public sealed class PositionTracker<T> : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly object _syncLock = new object();
    private readonly IList<T> _list = new List<T>();
    private int _current;

    public PositionTracker(IList<T> list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }

    public T GetCurrent()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            return _list[_current];
        }
    }

    public T GetNext()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            T t = GetCurrent();
            if (_current < _list.Count - 1)
            {
                _current++;
            }
            return t;
        }
    } 

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            return _list.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            _current = 0;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                return _list.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class PositionTrackerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Position_CurrentPosition_Test()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" });
        PositionTracker<string> positionTracker = new PositionTracker<string>(list);

        Assert.IsTrue(positionTracker.GetNext().Equals("A"));
        Assert.IsTrue(positionTracker.GetNext().Equals("B"));
        Assert.IsTrue(positionTracker.GetNext().Equals("C"));
        Assert.IsTrue(positionTracker.GetNext().Equals("D"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `yield` keyword. [Especially this link of Chapter 6 of the Book 'C# in Depth' By Jon Skeet](http://www.manning-source.com/books/skeet/Chapter6sample.pdf)

P.S. I hope you are doing it in C#.NET 2.0+

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: [foreach with generic List, detecting first iteration when using value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420774/foreach-with-generic-list-detecting-first-iteration-when-using-value-type/420797#420797)

There is a link to a [`SmartEnumerable`](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) class by Jon Skeet. It is basically a wrapper for IEnumerable, which gives you a public `SmartEnumerable<string>.Entry` class which contains the item's index.

Also, nothing stops you from doing this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     private List<String> list = new List<String>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }

     public IEnumerable<String> GetItems(int from, int to)
     {
          for (int i=from; i<to; i++)
               yield return list[i];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve most of this with an extension method, and overloads of `Enumerable.Select` and `Where`.

Both `Select` and `Where` have overloads where the delegate is passed both the item and its index:

```
var input = new[]{'a','b','c','d'};
var indexed = input.Select((v,i) => new { Value = v, Index = i });
foreach (var v in indexed) {
  Console.WriteLine("Index #{0} is '{1}'", v.Index, v.Value);
}
```

To trigger delegates before the first and after the last items (but only if there is at least one item):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> StartAndEnd<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input,
                                     Action onFirst,
                                     Action onLast) {
  var e = input.GetEnumerator();
  if (!e.MoveNext()) { yield break; }
  onFirst();
  do {
    yield return e.Current;
  } while (e.MoveNext());
  onLast();
}
```

and then use it as:

```
var input = new[]{'a','b','c','d'};
var indexed = input.StartAndEnd(() => { Console.WriteLine("First!");},
                                () => { Console.WriteLine("Last!");})
                   .Select((v,i) => new { Value = v, Index = i });
foreach (var v in indexed) {
  Console.WriteLine("Index #{0} is '{1}'", v.Index, v.Value);
}
```

which gives the result:

```
First!
Index #0 is 'a'
Index #1 is 'b'
Index #2 is 'c'
Index #3 is 'd'
Last!
```

The delegates could set a local (by forming a closure) which is checked in a loop.

A more sophisticated version could call the onLast delegate before the last element of the sequence, but this would require buffering an element of the sequence to detect end before yielding that element.