# IList<T> versus Collection<T> as property

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class with a internal array field.  I want to expose this array as a property, such that it maintains as much funtionallity of the orginal array but does not violate encapsulation by exposing the array directly.  What are the various methods and pros and cons?  I'm thinking specifically about `IList<T>` or `Colleciton<T>`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-listt-or-ilistt

Comment: What methods do you require in your public interface?

Comment: As the underlying type is an array who's length is fixed by the class, I mainly need access and assignment by index enumeration capability.  I don't want users to be able to add/delete/resize the unerlying array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IList<T>` is bettere as it is a descendant of the ICollection generic interface and is the base interface of all generic lists. Along with you also have advantage for having funcionality from following interfaces

```
IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable
```

this is the signature:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

see following for details

[`IList<T> Interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)

Comment: `IList<T>` seems like the best choice as it allows for access\assignment by index.  `ICollection<T>` does not support indexing.  The only drawback is that `IList<T>` exposes `Add` and `Remove` methods that will throw a `NotSupportedException` if called.

Answer (score 2):

An IList is an ICollection:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

You could implement ICollection, and if you need more methods from IList in the future, you can just change it without causing harm to the clients.

Answer (score 2):

The corrrect way to do this is to expose a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) that wraps the array.

If you expose the array as an interface, malicious code can cast it back to an array and modify the values behind your back.

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection violates LSP and forces the input collection to implement `IList<T>` which is quite restrictive however.

Comment: @Lee: the input collection is an array.

Comment: It might be an array now, but if he wants to change it (to a linked list say) then he will have difficulty since he's exposing a ReadOnlyCollection but `LinkedList<T>` doesn't implement `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd expose it as `IEnumerable<T>` and let the client decide which is best since this will give you the most freedom to change the underlying storage. If you really want to use `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` I'd choose `ICollection<T>` for the same reason.