# How to combine objects into one list, when they are inherited from one interface?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm learning C# and trying to do simple object oriented exercise.

I have three weapon classes, "Bow,dagger,Spear", so I made one interface and inherited from this interface IWeapon.

Now user must choose one of the weapon, so I want to make Collection of weapons and I'm trying to make list of IWeapons, is it correct way? Isn't it bad practice to make list type of IWeapon ? Because of, I know that Interfaces are like a contracts, and I think it's a bad idea to make List with Interface type. One way is to change interface to an abstract class, but I want to use Interface.

```
 private static List<IWeapon> weapons = new List<IWeapon>();
```

Is it correct way or not ?

Comment: Yes, no issue on this as long as all three weapon classes not having their own properties....

Comment: Yes, I believe there is nothing wrong with having a list of interface. Your design ok

Comment: This is actually a pretty common pattern, nothing wrong here.

Comment: Although your appraoch is quite good such questions are quite opinion-based and thus bad on StackOverflow.

Comment: You may have no choice over this exercise but might want to read Eric Lippert's blog series entitled [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) (link to part 1, 5 parts in all)

Comment: Thank you guys for great response. I'm trying to build my structure in such way, that next time every new weapon can easily added

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3564264/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your solution is that static members should be thread-safe. It's like a convention among C# developers. So either change it to a non-static and, preferrably, readonly:

```
private readonly List<IWeapon> weapons = new List<IWeapon>();
```

Or use a thread-safe collection:

```
private static ConcurrentBag<IWeapon> weapons = new ConcurrentBag<IWeapon>();
```

Comment: I have never heard about a convention like this. Best practice is to not program for thread-safety unless required, since this increases complexity.

Comment: @Sefe MS guarantees that all static .NET APIs are thread safe. If you'll look into other popular libraries, it is always thread-safe with static members. Best practice is to not releasing code at all (you'll need to support it in future)

Comment: *"static members should to be thread-safe"* - only if multhreading is a concern, but with given question it's hard to judge to give such recommendations.

Comment: @Sinatr if no multithreading - then why static? That's why I showed two options

Comment: There are several of reasons to have static members in single-thread environment. Making every static member thread-safe simply doesn't make sense. My comment is mostly about "should" word and why involving multi-threading at all if OP is not speaking of it.

Comment: By far the large majority of code is not in puplished libraries. It is completely absurd to go for thread safety if it is not required. And even in published libraries, nobody keeps you from limiting the use to a single threaded environment.

Comment: @Sefe Using your words: it is absolutely absurd to code if it is not required. Large majority of code is not written at all. Nobody keeps you from not coding. So what is your conclusion?

Comment: A good start would have been not writing the code in your answer.

Comment: *"absurd to code if it is not required"* - leads to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) ;) Simply put, your answer is correct and useful, but only if multithreading is under the question.

Comment: @astef _"if no multithreading - then why static?"_ Are you claiming that the only use case for a static is in a multithreaded application? Because that's simply not the case. Your answer is a good footnote, it is not a direct answer to the current question.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using interfaces as values for lists.

However, this may not be appropriate to your specific case. You said you'd like the player to pick from a list of weapons. Now consider the follwing scenarios:

1. *You have a single player in your game, and he chose a single weapon.* You have created a whole list worth of weapon instances that no one will ever need or use. This just wastes memory.
2. *You have multiple players in the game, and they both choose the same weapon.* This could be even worse. If you assign the weapons like this: `player.Weapon = weapons[1]`, then both players will have the same **instance** of the weapon. If one user assings buffs to his weapons, or maybe if the weapon degrades or breaks, **both** the players weapons will be affected, since it is, in fact, the same weapon. Think of it like this, both you and I would like a chocolate cake. The store can either give us both the same piece of cake, in this case, if you eat it, I will have none. Or they can bake us both new cakes, so each of us can have his own.

The appropriate solution in this case is to save the types of weapons and present these to the player. Then create a new weapon instance according to the player's choice.

There are several different ways to do this, the simplest of which is to create an enum with the weapon types and present these to the player.

So instead of the list, you can have:

```
public enum WeaponType
{
    Bow,
    Dagger,
    Spear
}
```

And now you need to create the instance of the weapon the player chose:

```
public IWeapon CreateWeapon(WeaponType weaponType)
{
    switch(weaponType)
    {
        case WeaponType.Bow:
        // Create Bow...
        case WeaponType.Dagger:
        // Create Dagger...
        case WeaponType.Spear:
        // Create Spear...
    }
}
```

This is the basis to the Factory design pattern. I would highly recommend you to take a look at it. Here's a good place to start: http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Comment: Thank you very much, Your answer helped me a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I have two thoughts on this:

1. I can easily imagine a situation where one would want to use a collection of a particular interface. For example, if you were writing a download queue. You would have weapons and shields and players and villages which all implement an IDownloadableThing interface. Your queue code would have a collection of IDownloadableThings because it doesn't care what its actually downloading, it just cares that that thing know what its URL or file path or whatever is.
2. I'm a little wary of developer edicts. There are good ideas and traps you should be aware of in any language, but context can change everything. When you are trying to figure out if 'Weapon' should be an abstract class, ask yourself a couple things. Should a class implementing Weapon also be allowed to be a Shield? If locking down multiple inheritance is important, then abstract classes are the way to do that. Will there be a lot or any common behavior that classes implementing 'Weapon' will want to share? For example, is there a CalculateDamage() method that's basically identical between all 'Weapon' implementations. Once you have answers to what a class of interface's purpose is, then it'll be easier to choose to violate a development guideline because the situation requires it or re-think your approach.