# C# DAL returing generic List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

Could I return List  from my DAL ?, In internet I read somewhere that it's not good.
What is the problem if return List ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - List<T> or IList<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-listt-or-ilistt)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return a `List<T>` object, but the property should be *typed* `IList<T>` instead.  This will allow you to change the list implementation that you use at a later time, without breaking binary compatibility with existing assemblies compiled against your library.

This example probably won't match your constructor pattern, but it demonstrates what I mean (returning a `List<T>` through an `IList<T>` property):

```
public class Foo
{
    public IList<string> AListOfStrings { get; private set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        AListOfStrings = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just returning `IEnumerable<T>`? That's even more flexible.

Comment: @John: Perhaps, but I would favor `ICollection<T>` over `IEnumerable<T>`.  If this is a DAL class, modification may be necessary, and modifying IEnumerables is non-trivial, while `ICollection<T>` exposes mutating methods.

Comment: If you don't need indexing or count, you can use `IEnumerable<T>`, and then you would have more flexibility, like the option to return a lazy enumeration.

Comment: @cdhowie: `ICollection<T>` is making assumptions about how the collection will be used. I'd rather not do that.

Comment: @John: Same with `IEnumerable<T>`.  Only the developer will be able to effectively choose which is appropriate.

Comment: @cdhowie: nonsense. `IEnumerable<T>` simply assumes it will be enumerated! An `ICollection<T>` is something that can be modified.

Comment: what about (sorry could not insert line breaks) , public ICollection<School> GetSchool()
     {

  ICollection<School> schoolList = new List<School>();
 .....
 return schoolList.ToList();
   }

Comment: @John: That's exactly my point.  If the point is to expose a modifiable collection to the caller, `IEnumerable<T>` is not going to cut it.  That's why the developer will have to choose which type makes the most sense for their application.

Comment: @kayak: There is no need to type `schoolList` as `ICollection<School>` -- you can use `List<School>` there.  And the `ToList()` call is unnecessary.  Just return `schoolList`; `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, so no conversion is necessary.

Comment: @cdhowie, Thanks  i found some more links related to it    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-listt-or-ilistt

Comment: @cdhowie: it depends on what the DAL is trying to expose. I don't believe I've ever seen a DAL return a modifiable collection, unless it was planning to ignore any modifications, in which case I'd prefer it return `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

In principle, there's no problem with returning `List<T>`, however a common problem is when classes return a member `List<T>` variable which violates encapsulation e.g.

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; private set; }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        T first = Items[0];
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case, any clients of this class can modify its state which could lead to bugs since the class can no longer protect its invariants. Note that returning `IList<T>` in this case will not help.

For a data access object however, it will (hopefully) not retain the results of any queries, so a new copy of the list will be returned each time and it will not be affected by the modifications of any clients.

Comment: if any modifications to the list will be ignore anyway, why not return `IEnumerable<T>`. It seems more honest.