# Why should I return IList<T> over List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-listt-or-ilistt)

It's written all over SO that you should return `IList<T>` from your methods and not `List<T>` but I can't find any really good reasons why. I keep finding code that does this, and then the calling code usually does one of two things:

1. Call `new List<T>(returnedIList)` so it can use all the nice methods on List
2. Casts back to `List<T>` so it can use all the nice methods on List

The first one is clunky and the second one would throw *(runtime)* `InvalidCastException` if the implementation actually changed to something else anyway (which makes it *totally* stupid).

If I use `List<T>` and for some reason have to replace it with an implementation of `IList<T>` that I can't inherit from `List<T>` then I'll get build errors and have to change some code. That's probably very unlikely and if it happens, it's not a lot of work to fix. Surely it's not worth losing the benefits of `List<T>` and/or having to cast/new `List<T>` (Exists, Find, etc.) to get them back for this unlikely scenario?

So, are there other reasons are there for returning `IList<T>`?

Comment: Not only is it "written all over SO", this very question has already been asked and answered!

Comment: Apologies - after 3 pages of results I gave up looking - SO "Relevance" seems to be a little off for me lately! Going with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-listt-or-ilistt/1522826#1522826 ;D

Comment: No apology needed, search on SO is of limited utility. I searched on Google with site:stackoverflow.com! to find the dupe!

Comment: heh, good idea. Though if the SO search isn't so good, I'm surprised they're not using the Google API themselves :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is so that your method can be used with anything that implements `IList<T>`, and not just a List. It gets even worse, though, since the advent of Linq, I've started making a lot of stuff return `Enumerable<T>` or even just `IEnumerable`!

I am not sure I understand the difficulty, though. If something is returning an actual list, and its return depends on that, or its use is specific to that, then it should return `List<T>`. If not, then you should have no need to cast it to a List.

Comment: I suspect the calling code was written after the method, and the programmer was reluctant to change the method to return a concrete List - and I'm trying to understand if that decision is justified.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds to me like you're looking at some poor quality code.

Returning `IList<T>` rather than `List<T>` allows your code to be more flexible. You can replace the implementation with any collection that implements `IList<T>` without breaking any calling code. That's a good thing...but only when the functionality defined in `IList<T>` matches your needs.

You can generalize that to say that you should always return the most generic type possible. In most cases, you can get away with `IEnumerable<T>` but if you need more functionality, then `IList<T>` works. If that doesn't cut it, return the concrete type and be done with it.

In both of the situations you mention, there is a need to use something not directly provided by `IList<T>` (and if there's not, then both of those methods are in error). In those cases, either the method should return `List<T>` to provide the functionality needed or the caller should be using another method.

Comment: Yeah! It's exactly what everybody say about the best practices. However, probably because I'm working the vast majority of the time with code that is more oriented with features at a more high level of abstraction (like business rules), I didn't had in the last 12 years a situation where I have to change the implementation. However, I can see cases when you deal with class that implement list<T> and you want this class to be inherited by other some cases where there is a benefit to use IList over List.

Answer (score 1):

Really you should return IEnumerable if possible, otherwise IList.

Th reason is that you may want to use something else than a List in the future. It is not uncommon to implement your own list that implements IList and then you do not need to change most of your code.

Search for derived types from IList and you see that you get many hits just within the .NET framework!

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't work for what a lot of this code does (and I'd love to change it - for one, I hate loading everything into memory when we could "stream" through results). If we were to implement a custom list, I'd imagine we'd be more likely to start from List<T> than roll the entire thing?

Comment: IEnumerable is actually a great way to return stuff that may end up being used as a list, because new Lists can be directly created from an IEnumerable (like your first example). I couldn't say for sure but I suspect the overhead of doing this, compared to returning a new List object directly, is zero. Something that returns IEnumerable should be implemented with `yield`, therefore not actually creating any new list object. So the number of times you instantiate a list and add elements to it would be identical either way.

Comment: Yes I know that IEnumerable<T> won't fit the bill always, but if it does you can all by a sudden use things like fixed arrays and IQuerables, which helps a lot once you have gotten used to it. More advanced lists does not need to extend List at all, one example  might be lazy loading lists that have a totally different storage strategy than List - so yes List may be the base but I usually do not use it (in that case I wrap it instead).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to let the caller decide what collection they'll use.  You see a lot of people returning `IEnumerable<T>` whenever they can.  It's generally considered good practice to do so.  Returning IList let's the caller use whichever implementation of IList they prefer when returning List requires them to manually copy the List's data in their data collection of choice.

Returning IEnumerable is ideal.

Comment: I don't understand how returning IList lets the caller decide on the implementation (we're talking about returning, not accepting as an argument, if that's what you meant)

Comment: I'll take the example of IEnumerable as more classes implement that interface.  When I call a method that returns an IEnumerable, I can decide only to foreach() through it or create a List/Queue/Stack/SortedList, etc with it.  It allows me to use the implementation of the IEnumerable interface I prefer.  On the other hand, returning a List forces me to either use a list or create a Stack for example and manually enter every item from the List in my Stack.

Comment: If I return List you could also create any of these (since List is IEnumerable)!