# C# Using IList instead of List

Tags: c#, list, ilist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-listt-or-ilistt)

I'm working on a solution have noticed there is a lot fo IList being implemented. 
Just wondering, what is the point of using an IList when you can use a List?

Comment: Found a link to the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-listt-or-ilistt

Comment: please provide a specific question for a specific answer.

Comment: The duplicate is the first result (ignoring this one) that you get in 'related questions', when you try to ask this as well... ;) Which is why you ask your QUESTION in the title, and explain any DETAILS in the  description box...

Answer (score 1):

Because some collections may inherit from IList and not from List, ObservableCollection for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want don't want to inherit `List` and just want to implement the interface use `IList`.

Perhaps you want to return an object that supports `IList` but the implementation is irrelavant to the caller?

In your case implementing `IList` may result in unesscessary typing, it may be right thing to do, I' can't know without more info.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to use the `interface` where possible to allow the user to have more flexibility on which implementation they use. Generally, `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` are even better than `IList` as they're more generic, unless you want to limit this with good reason of course.