# Does T[] implement IList<T>?

Tags: c#

I have a class constructor that takes a `IList<IElement>` as an argument.

When creating a new instance of the class I'm able to pass a `IElement[]` instead of the `IList<IElement>` how is that posible?

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163297/how-do-arrays-in-c-sharp-partially-implement-ilistt

Comment: `"How and why is this possible?"` - You should get a badge for either clickbait or poorly phrased title.

Comment: @RoyiNamir .. But this is not about array covariance.

Comment: @royi This behavious comes from the compiler implementing the interfaces on array types for you, for various reasons.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Even if it was invariant, you would still be able to convert `IElement[]` into `IList<IElement>`, simply because single-dimensional arrays are given this implementation at runtime. `T[]` implements `IList<T>`. See the post linked by Adam Houldsworth.

Comment: @dcastro Jon says in the answer attached to this question : _Well, I believe it's really due to array covariance_

Comment: @RoyiNamir You've taken that quote out of context.  That line isn't referring to the fact that `T[]` implements `IList<T>`.  It's referring to entirely separate, although related, properties of how arrays implement their interfaces, namely that they are covariant, and they need to maintain that covariance through these interfaces.

Comment: @RoyiNamir He's referring to the fact that `GetInterfaceMap` fails.

Comment: I will read it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An array with element type `T` derives from `IList<T>`.

This is not visible in the meta-data in mscorlib.dll, but the inheritance relationship is created at runtime in the CLR. C# and the CLR are aware of the array type and treat it specially.

Comment: It does [not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11164210/284240) ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Does [too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11163336/358221)! ... eventually ;-)