# C# and .Net why do all arrays inherit from IList?

Tags: c#, list

I recently noticed that all arrays in C# inherit from the IList interface but you can't really handle an array like a standard list.

Why was this inheritance introduced in .net and C#

Comment: A list and an array are different data structures. It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163297/how-do-arrays-in-c-sharp-partially-implement-ilistt

Comment: Arrays may **implement** `IList`, they do not inherit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often useful to be able to pass *any* `IList` to some algorithm. That algorithm might just care about being able to index into this collection. Many things fulfill this requirement: Arrays, `List<T>`, many custom collections.