# How can Array use LINQ extension methods since Array does not implent IEnumerable<T> interface

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my program :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int[] myArr = new int[] { 4,6,2,1};

        //call Where() linq method
        var myEvenNumbers = myArr.Where(n => n % 2 == 0 );

        Console.Read();
}
```

but when i look the definition of Where() extension method in Enumerable class

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate);
```

The type of the source is `IEnumerable<T>`.

My question is: Array class does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` but how can we still use the Where() extension method on an array ?

Comment: Class `Array` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` when `T[]` *does* - `IEnumerable<int>`. Since `Array` and `T[]` are *different* classes  nothing wrong with them.

Comment: If you read the ReferenceSource comments on `System.SZArrayHelper` it will shed *some* light on the problem. Hans Passant's explanation available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163297/how-do-arrays-in-c-sharp-partially-implement-ilistt/11164210#11164210

Comment: Could you tell me documentation for T[ ] class i want to have a look at this class.

Answer (score 3):

An array does implement IEnumerable as well as ICollection (and their generics) and a host of other ones

```
foreach (var type in (new int[3]).GetType().GetInterfaces())
    Console.WriteLine(type);
```

Produces

[image]

Comment: That's a nice `Console.WriteLine` you've got there.

Comment: @Rawling it is from LinqPad

Comment: Try `(new int[3]).GetType().GetInterfaces().Dump()` instead :)

Answer (score 3):

Array doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, which you'd see if you tried to use something that requires `IEnumerable<T>` with a variable actually typed as `Array`.  The type-specific array types (like `int[]` as in your example) *do* implement `IEnumerable<T>`, along with other generic types.

Comment: The type-specific array types do implement IEnumerable<T>. how can i know ? can you provide any document please. Thanks.

Comment: Well, for starters there is this passage on the MSDN documentation page for System.Array: `Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>, and System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> generic interfaces` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx)