# C# Converting Arrays to IENumerable<T>

Tags: c#, arrays

Arrays are non-generic. They implement `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`. So how is it possible that the following code compiles and executes fine ?

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4};
IEnumerable<int> myEnum = myArray;
List<int> myList = new List<int>(myArray);
```

Comment: Arrays *do* implement `IEnumerable<T>`, see the linked duplicate question for details.

Comment: [Why do arrays in .net only implement IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773740/why-do-arrays-in-net-only-implement-ienumerable-and-not-ienumerablet)

Comment: @Heinzi: Well, some do. Not all. `int[,]` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<int>` for example...

Comment: SZArrays (single-rank arrays with 0 as the lower bound) implement `IEnumerable<T>` (and `IList<T>`), but they do so in a different way to how classes and structs implement arrays, so some of the things we'd expect to see when an interface is implemented, we don't. `typeof(int[]).GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IEnumerable<int>))` for example throws an exception. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31883327/400547 explains how they are implemented and why these differences happen.

Comment: @Heinzi, yes it is a duplicate, my bad, i hadnt seen those previous posts. Thanks