# does array implements IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I know that the base abstract Array class doesn't implement generic IEnumerable as

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
{
 ...
}
```

so when I create a derive array class like `int[] i;` or `string[] s;`, do they implement `IEnumerable<T>`? And how can I see the source code of `[]`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163297/how-do-arrays-in-c-sharp-partially-implement-ilistt

Comment: https://mattwarren.org/2017/05/08/Arrays-and-the-CLR-a-Very-Special-Relationship/ may be worth a read.

Comment: That looks a lot like my answer.  What a coincidence.

Comment: Matt Warren does point to that stackoverflow link for further reading @HansPassant.

Answer (score 3):

Official word here

[Array Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

> An array has the following properties:
>
> - An array can be Single-Dimensional, Multidimensional or Jagged.
> - The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are established when the array instance is created. These values can't be
>     changed during the lifetime of the instance.
> - The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null.
> - A jagged array is an array of arrays, and therefore its elements are reference types and are initialized to null.
> - Arrays are zero indexed: an array with n elements is indexed from 0 to n-1.
> - Array elements can be of any type, including an array type.
> - **Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. Since this type implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`,
>     you can use `foreach` iteration on all arrays in C#.**

Comment: This is a mighty fine summary of `Array`, but it doesn't answer the question "And how can I see the source code of `[]`?"

Comment: @TheGeneral is it the reason we can use extension methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable` because the derived array types do implement IEnumerable<T> despite the fact that base Array class doesn't?

Comment: @Enigmativity and there be the fly in the anointment (again). technically there isn't really its compiled

Answer (score 3):

There is special type `SZArrayHelper` - wrapper around array. Here is source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,aa97964558672440

Also, array implements `IList`, and it implements `ICollection` and it implements `IEnumerable`. So, Array implements `IEnumerable`

Comment: You got to love the constructor `Contract.Assert(false, "Hey! How'd I get here?");` someone at Microsoft has a sense of humour, also plus 1

Comment: @TheGeneral i've found it after investigating another problem: http://blog.rogatnev.net/2017/07/14/IndexOf-with-IEquatable.html

Answer (score 2):

You can check it simply like this:

```
var type = typeof(int[]); // or any other type
foreach (var @interface in type.GetInterfaces())
    Console.WriteLine(@interface);
```

Result is:

```
System.ICloneable
System.Collections.IList
System.Collections.ICollection
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Collections.IStructuralComparable
System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Int32]
```