# Difference between IList<T> and List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-sharp-listt-or-ilistt)

I have a class

```
 public class Employee
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

And I need to define a list and what is the difference between defining it in below ways

```
IList<Employee> EmpList ;

Or

List<Employee> EmpList ;
```

Answer (score 14):

`IList<>` is an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). `List<>` is a concrete class.

Any of these will be valid:

```
 IList<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();
```

and

```
 List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();
```

or

```
 var EmpList = new List<Employee>(); // EmpList is List<Employee>
```

However, you cannot instantiate an interface, i.e. the following will fail:

```
IList<Employee> EmpList = new IList<Employee>();
```

In general, classes and methods which use dependencies (such as collections) should specify the least restrictive interface possible (i.e. the most general one). e.g. if your method just needs to iterate a collection, then an `IEnumerable<>` will suffice:

```
public void IterateEmployees(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
   foreach(var employee in employees)
   {
     // ...
   }
}
```

Whereas if a consumer needs to access the `Count` property (as opposed to having to iterate the collection via `Count()`), then a `ICollection<T>` or better, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` would be more appropriate, and similarly, `IList<T>` would only be required when needing random access to the collection via `[]` or to express that new items need to be added or removed from the collection.

Answer (score 7):

`IList<T>` is an interface implemented by `List<T>.`

You cannot create a concrete instance of an interface so:

```
//this will not compile
IList<Employee> EmpList = new IList<Employee>();    

//this is what you're really looking for:
List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();

//but this will also compile:
IList<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();
```

Comment: yes i agree but i want to know depending on what situation we need to decide which to use:
List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();

IList<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();

Answer (score 6):

There are two answers here. For storing the actual list, use an `List<T>` because you need a concrete data structure. However, if you return it from a property or require it as an argument, consider a `IList<T>`. It is more generic, allowing more types to be passed it for the argument. Similarly, it allows more types to be returned than just the `List<T>` in case the internal implementation changes. Indeed, you may want to consider an `IEnumerable<T>` for the return type instead.

Comment: At which point we need to use IList and List ? I know IList is an interface and List inherit this interface. Please see below example - public class Test

Comment: @user1521931 This is a design question. In general, I would recommend using `List<T>` for your fields and `IList<T>` for properties and arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave you to enumerate the differences, perhaps with some nifty reflection, but a `List<T>` implements several interfaces, and `IList<T>` is only one of them:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
    IEnumerable
```

Answer (score 2):

`List` object allows you to create a list, add things to it, remove it, update it, index into it etc etc. `List` is used whenever you just want a generic List where you specify object type in it and that's it.

`IList` on the other hand is an Interface. (For more on interfaces see MSDN Interfaces). Basically, if you want to create your own type of `List`, say a list class called SimpleList, then you can use the Interface to give you basic methods and structure to your new class. `IList` is for when you want to create your own, special sub-class that implements `List`.
[You can see example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/325178/Difference-between-ilist-and-list-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of Lists. Each of them inherits from an IList (which is why it's an interface). Two examples are the List (regular list), and a Paged List (this is a list that has support for paging - it is used commonly in paged search results). A Paged List and a List are both types of ILists, which means that an IList is not necessary a List (it can be a Paged List) or vice-versa.

See this link on a PagedList. https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList#readme

Answer (score 0):

IList is an interface, List is a class that implements it, the List type explicitly implements the non generic IList interface

Answer (score 0):

The first version is programming to interfaces and is preferred (assuming you only need to use the methods defined by IList). The second version, with its declaration based on a specific class, is unnecessarily rigid.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that IList is an interface and List is a class.
List implements IList, but IList can't be instantiated.