# Why using interface in Dictionary declaration?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I noticed this code in our project

```
Dictionary<int, IList> someDict = new Dictionary<int, IList>();
```

What's the idead of using interface for value? Does that means that I can put in every list that implements/support IList ? For example, can I put L `List<int>`and `List<string>` for values in the dictionary ?

Comment: You can put any implementation of `IList` as a value for some key.

Comment: change "every list that inherits from IList" to "every list that implements/supports from IList"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows you to have a more generic type, so it will become easier to refactor if you change the type later.

[List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-sharp-listt-or-ilistt)

The best way to reduce refactoring job is to use IEnumerable when possible.

Comment: But 'IEnumrable' is not suitable in the cases when you need to add or delete elements, since it doesn't support them ? In that cases, 'IList" is preferable. I got the idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can put any implementation of `IList` as a value

```
Dictionary<int, IList> someDict = new Dictionary<int, IList>();
someDict[1] = new List<string>() { "Hello", "World" };
someDict[2] = new List<int>() { 42 };
someDict[3] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
someDict[4] = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to be decoupled from a special class, you just want to make sure that the type used in the dictionary provides the IList funcionality. As long as your type provides this you can use it, including `List<T>`. It's like a contract which ensures a set of methods/properties on the type

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use types that inherit from from type declared. In your case `List<int>` is generic type built from `List<T>`, which in turn inherits from `IList`. For that reason, yes, you can use `List<int>` in your dictionary.