# ilist vs list.why and when we use from both.give me practical scenario

Tags: c#, list

I know that `IList` is the interface and `List` is the concrete type but I still don't know when to use each one. Is there a better way to decide when to use the interface or the concrete type with some practical scenario.

I want to know why I use `IList` and why I use `List` in our project.

Comment: I have already studied various sites but can't get in deeply. i want to know the practical example for both list..which one will be best to implement in project and performance wise which one is better.

Comment: @ShivaniSharma There is a practical example further down that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad and could probably be solved by a search. Have a look at this post: [List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/listt-or-ilistt).
Also refer to theese pages (among others) if you need guidance as to which collection to use:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx