# Type Exception when adding seperate groups to a listview in forms and deploying to IOS with live

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

So i am trying to add multiple groups of items to a listview in xamarin forms. It works perfectly fine with just simple objects as such:

```
todoListView.ItemsSource = new List<TodoItem> 
            {
                    new TodoItem{ TimeLeft="13:30", Location="The Room", Title="IM AN URGENT TITLE!", ImageURL="Unread.png", Unread=true, TodoText="This is some random text to illustrate a useless point." },
                    new TodoItem{ Title="IM A TITLE!", ImageURL="Unread.png", Unread=true, TodoText="This is some random text to illustrate a useless point." }
            };
```

But when i add a group like this:

```
    todoListView.ItemsSource = new List<TodoListGroups>
    {
        new TodoListGroups("Test")
        {
            new TodoItem{ Title="IM A TITLE!", ImageURL="Unread.png", Unread=true, TodoText="This is some random text." }
        }
    };
```

I get the following error: Object of type 'Ninterpret.interpretedObject' doesn't match type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Ninterpret.interpretedObject]' (TargetException)

```
My model looks like this:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace xyz
{
    public class TodoListGroups : List<TodoItem>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public TodoListGroups(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

The xaml for reference is:

```
<ContentPage Icon="list.png" Title="Todos">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <ListView SeparatorColor="OrangeRed" x:Name="todoListView" HasUnevenRows="True" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}"></Image>
                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding TodoText}" TextColor="Gray"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Button Text="Done"></Button>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you should extend TodoListGroup from IList or ICollection and not from List

Comment: Can you help me understand the difference? Is IList an extension?

Comment: IList is an interface which is implemented by List. This is a much exhaustive  explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/listt-or-ilistt