# Using List<T> vs. IList<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use IList and when to use List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170/when-to-use-ilist-and-when-to-use-list)

This question could just be a lack of understanding of the .NET framework, but what is the benefit of actually having a set of data in an interface rather than just having it in a list? Up to this point I have only used `List<T>` and it seems to do pretty much what I need it to do, but looking at other peoples code I see that it is quite frequent for someone to use `IEnumerable<T>`, `IQueryable`/`IQueryable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, and even `IList<T>`. That being said, what is even the difference between `List<T>` and `IList<T>`?

I understand that some of them have different functionality on the contained objects, but which is the most safest to go with? `IEnumerable`?

Comment: It's good practise to use only what you need. So if a method does only use methods and properties of `IList`, why should it enforce a `List` as parameter? Note that an `Array` also implements `IList`.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the type to an interface type, you can use *any* type that implements `IList<T>`.

If you use `List<T>` you can only use that type and types that inherit from it.

It depends on usage - if you only need to iterate, use `IEnumerable<T>`, if you also need to add/remove items, use `ICollection<T>`. If you need to index into the collection, use `IList<T>`, etc...